# Bernoulli Naive Bayes Classification

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, naive-bayes

I am having trouble understanding the following text regarding Bernoulli Naive Bayes. 
Specifically, the author mentions that $i$ is a feature. However, what is the difference between $x_i$ and $i$?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the decision rule formula to hold, $x_i$ needs to be binary and $P(i | y) = P(x_i = 1 | y)$ (think about the formula in the case where $x_i = 1$ and the case where $x_i = 0$). So $i$ is the event $x_i = 1$.